# Display a dialog upon login asking for the login reason - Windows Server

Tags: windows, login, dialog

I'm looking for a way to display an input dialog upon login to a production server, asking the user to indicate the reason of the login. I was thinking maybe there's a way in Windows to do it that is similar to the Shutdown dialog that is displayed whenever a server is restarted.

I've looked in the Group Policy but couldn't find anything useful. I know this can be done by a script but I was looking to see if there's any integrated way in Windows before I start writing it.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing, by default, available in Group Policy to do this. How are your Powershell chops?  Also, how are you planning to "store" the responses provided?

Comment: I can go with Powershell (although it's been a while...) and yes I plan to store the responses, preferably in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Can I just type a period or a space character for my reason, just like I do for the real Windows dialogs that ask me why I'm rebooting the server?  :)

Comment: You can, but then we'll have nice talk in the next team meeting :)

Comment: Why not just audit logon events, make everyone use a named account, and parse the Security event log?

Comment: I wonder if you can do something similar to the "computer shut down unexpectedly" prompt you get on login to a computer that did just that.  Something that would call the same type of window/box with options that write to the system event log.

Comment: joeqwerty, because I'm trying to get the users to document the reason of the login. we're already using named accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing the following VBScript and set it to run on Logon in the GPO

```vb
' Display an input dialog asking the reason for a login and writes it to the event viewer with information of the user.

Const EVENT_TYPE = "Information" 'Available Values: Success, Error, Warning, Information
Const EVENT_SOURCE = "LoginAudit" 'Setting the event source requires that the script runs with administrative privileges

firstname = GetUserFirstname()
username = GetUsername()

loginReason = ""
Do While (loginReason = "")
    loginReason = InputBox("Hi " + firstname + ", please describe the reason of your login:", "Login Audit")
Loop

eventDescription = "User '" & username & "' logged in, providing the following reason: " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & loginReason

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "eventcreate /T " & EVENT_TYPE & " /ID 100 /L Application /SO LoginAudit /D " & _
    Chr(34) & eventDescription & Chr(34)
WshShell.Run strcommand

Function GetUserFirstname()
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set objCurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
    GetUserFirstname = objCurrentUser.givenName
End Function

Function GetUsername()
    Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
    GetUsername = objNetwork.UserName
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

> I was looking to see if there's any integrated way in Windows before I start writing it.

No, there isn't. You're going to have to write it yourself I'm afraid. There might be a third party application that does what you want, but I'm afraid product/service recommendations are off topic here on Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping for something out of the box but I ended up writing a script eventually.