# GDPR - Server access logging at the point of authentication

Tags: windows, audit, data-protection

In the UK are are undergoing a large reform of data protection policy known as GDPR. For one client we need to beef up our auditing on access to certain servers by our support and development team. I want to know not only who logged in to a servers remote desktop, but why. 
I could simply create a excel spreadsheet or helpdesk entry and ask people to complete each time they logged in but it really isn't robust enough.

I have seen on other environments that at the point of logging into the server (at the login form) a secondary form is presented asking why the person is logging in. The login is not allowed until the secondary form is completed.

I have searched for a product such as this but cannot locate it. Can anyone recommend any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Fault really isn't for product recommendations. There was a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/526414/display-a-dialog-upon-login-asking-for-the-login-reason-windows-server) on SF in 2013, and the OP ended up creating a logon script asking for the reason until it's given i.e. not empty:

> ```
> <!-- language: lang-vb -->
>
> ' Display an input dialog asking the reason for a login and writes it to the event viewer with information of the user.
>
> Const EVENT_TYPE = "Information" 'Available Values: Success, Error, Warning, Information
> Const EVENT_SOURCE = "LoginAudit" 'Setting the event source requires that the script runs with administrative privileges
>
> firstname = GetUserFirstname()
> username = GetUsername()
>
> loginReason = ""
> Do While (loginReason = "")
>     loginReason = InputBox("Hi " + firstname + ", please describe the reason of your login:", "Login Audit")
> Loop
>
> eventDescription = "User '" & username & "' logged in, providing the following reason: " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & loginReason
>
> Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> strCommand = "eventcreate /T " & EVENT_TYPE & " /ID 100 /L Application /SO LoginAudit /D " & _
>     Chr(34) & eventDescription & Chr(34)
> WshShell.Run strcommand
>
> Function GetUserFirstname()
>   Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
>   Set objCurrentUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
>   GetUserFirstname = objCurrentUser.givenName
> End Function
>
> Function GetUsername()
>   Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
>   GetUsername = objNetwork.UserName
> End Function
> ```

You could modify this to fit your needs. I think that this open form field approach attracts giving some one-letter answers instead of real reasons. A drop-down menu could be better, if all the actions can fall within known standard procedures. This being part of GDPR related work, you probably have already thought of these procedures for handling *personally identifiable information*.